# Posting data to a service

Tags: android, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I have created a SampleItem just to test:

```
public class SampleItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the method that I calling from th service looks like this:

```
public void send(SampleItem s)
{
    String siteName = s.Name;
}
```

And I am debugging this method, What I can notice is that the "s (sampleitem is null)"

This is the data I am sending trough fiddler:

```
{ "SampleItem" : { "Name": "MyComp"} }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong,

Request headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
```

Content-type: application/json
Host: localhost:30677
Content-Length: 54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,,

In json-string, I should name it to "s" instead for SampleItem